# Place a span at the bottom of a div container

Tags: css

I have this code below. I expected the `span` was placed at the bottom of the `div`, but it is still at the `top`.. why?

```
<div><span>jfalsf</span></div>
```

---

```
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background: yellow;
}
span {
  background: red;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: This css doesn't show nothing helpful

Comment: Can you show us the HTML?

Comment: @matewka there you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use positioning instead:

```
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    background: yellow;
    position:relative;
}
span {
    background: red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kzgzS/)**

Vertically aligning an element aligns the bottom of the element (and its descendants) with the bottom of the entire line, not to the bottom of the parent.